# Amazon web service Route 53 ignore domain name

Tags: amazon-web-services, dns, amazon-route53

I have a group of micro-services hosted on AWS, these services interact with each other through request/response using DNS name defined on Route 53 at which i created a new private zone named `api.io` and defined the DNSs for example `WSG_KAFKA`, in my code i have configure the DNS name with the zone name like `WSG_KAFKA.api.io` 
Is there is any way to ignore the domain name `api.io` and use the DNS name directly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use the hostname directly you need to edit your `/etc/resolv.conf` and add `search api.io` option, so your file may look like:

```
search api.io
nameserver 10.0.0.2
```

That will help to just search your hostname by just using `WSG_KAFKA`.

From the man [resolv.conf](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/resolv.conf.5.html):

```
search Search list for host-name lookup.
          The search list is normally determined from the local domain
          name; by default, it contains only the local domain name.
          This may be changed by listing the desired domain search path
          following the search keyword with spaces or tabs separating
          the names.  Resolver queries having fewer than ndots dots
          (default is 1) in them will be attempted using each component
          of the search path in turn until a match is found.  For
          environments with multiple subdomains please read options
          ndots:n below to avoid man-in-the-middle attacks and
          unnecessary traffic for the root-dns-servers.  Note that this
          process may be slow and will generate a lot of network traffic
          if the servers for the listed domains are not local, and that
          queries will time out if no server is available for one of the
          domains.

          The search list is currently limited to six domains with a
          total of 256 characters.
```